# How to display parameter in a single item's detail and not in a single listview item

Tags: java, android, list, android-intent, parameters

i'm trying to solve something that i'm not sure about. I wants to show a parameter call "decription" in the single item's detail when the single listview item is selected but the "decription" should not be displayed on the single listview item. I know where the problem lies but i'm not sure how do i solve it. Please kindly give me your suggestions! Here is my code that the mistake lies:

```
// Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESC, KEY_COUNTRY_NAME,
                            KEY_VENUE_NAME, KEY_START_TIME }, new int[] {
                            R.id.title,R.id.description, R.id.countryName, R.id.venueName,
                            R.id.startTime });

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            // selecting single ListView item
            ListView lv = getListView();

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String description = ((TextView) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.description)).getText().toString();

                    // Starting new intent
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, title);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);

                    startActivity(in);

                }
```

As you can see, the **KEY_DESC** is the one i'm talking about, but in order for me to use the **in.putextra(KEY_DESC, description);** for me to use the **in.getStringExtra** from another class. But the description gets from the **R.id.description** field which its declared in the **ListAdapter**, which is also displayed in the listview items. I wants to remove from the **description** from the **listview items** but still be able to use the **in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, ??)** method. May i know what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the description to be shown in the main list, just remove the UI element that represents the description from your res/layout/list-item.xml (it probably would be TextView with id=@description).

In that case you won't see the description, but will still be available throught the SimpleAdapter.

Comment: If i remove the TextView, what should i put for the String description = ((TextView)) view.findViewById(R.id.description)).getText().toString();?

And for the in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, ??) What should i put for the ??

Comment: Anyone knows how should i do it?~